# Reverse proxy and keep original domain url in nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I was looking for a lot of examples and still can't find resolution
I want use:

```
    location /example {
       proxy_pass http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx/;
   }
```

For now I have:
domain.com/example -> xxx.xxx.xx.xxx/index.php

But I need:
domain.com/example -> domain.com/example/index.php

Can you help?

Comment: Is `domain.com/example/index.php` still hosted at `xxx.xxx.xx.xxx`?

Comment: It is a different domain but I need content from xxx.xxx.xx.xxx using domain.com

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. If you want the URI sent upstream without modification, remove the trailing `/` from the `proxy_pass` statement. If you want the upstream server to receive a Host request header with the value `domain.com`, use `proxy_set_header Host $host;`